# AngularJS Sending Objects as Array For PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ngresource

I'm getting use to AngularJS ng-resource but I am having a problem serieliazing an array. My ng-resource is like this

```
app.factory('MyModel', ['$resource', 'api_domain',
function($resource, api_domain) {

        return $resource(api_domain + 'adsizes/:id', {
            id : '@id'
        }, {
            get : {method: 'GET', isArray: true }
        })

}]);
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
    app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', 'MyModel',
    function($scope, MyModel) {

        MyModel.get({
                    id : id,
                    'conditions': { 'join' : 'table2'}
                }, function() {

                });
});
```

The problem is it passes the conditions like so:

```
conditions:{"join":"table2"}
```

Which passes into php as a string that has to get decoded. My question is how can I pass the conditions as associative array for php?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use json_encode for that in PHP, as you can't send anything other than strings with a GET or POST request anyway ?

Comment: json_encode would make it a json string.

Comment: It would, I of course meant json_decode, converting the string to an object or array.

Comment: I could do that, but that would require modifying the PHP to suite that javascript, something I want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this to your get request and var dump $_GET.

?conditions[join]=table2

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter needs to be an array, rather than an object:

```
...
conditions: ['join', 'table2']
...
```

Comment: Not quite. The parameters are being passed through $GET so there is no need for php://input

Comment: The reason why I'm not doing it PHP is because I do not want to have to change all my php to accomdate this one change

Comment: In that case, you need to use an array--rather than an object--as the input. I'll update my answer accordingly.